# Working with 1bpp images

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a "performance critical" operation where I need to work with 1bpp images.
Actually I'm using the Bitmap class and I'm doing, each iteration of a graphic update cycle, a copy of the bitmap inside the byte array.

Watching my task manager, this is not that I can keep doing: it uses 2% cpu all time, I think it's quite a lot for something like an utility program.

I need to waste less memory as possible and almost 0 cpu. The image is 160x43, quite small.

Why I am not using directly the byte array? Easy: I would like to write over it, do some common operations which I don't want to rewrite by myself.

I can use obviusly a different image class (from wpf for example, I don't know). I need the possibility to work with a 1bpp image.

*Offtopic:*
I have the same "problem" with a 32bpp image, I need a way to work with it as an image while it is a byte array, I can't make a copy of my bytes each time!!! I'm wasting cpu in this way.

Comment: 2% is quite a lot? Seems very light to me. Why isn't it operating at 100%? Are you deliberately slowing it down?

Comment: I am deliberating slowing it down, but as I've said this is an utility and works in background, it's supposed to use less cpu as possible. Other programs working with this library doesn't use cpu (almost nothing), obviusly they are written in C++ so you have better memory management. I don't need to control memory very well (we have a lot to spare), but I need to control cpu usage, because this utility is supposed to work even during game execution

Comment: @spender, if this is supposed to be a background app, 2% constant CPU would be enough to get me annoyed.

Comment: @driis: I agree definitely with you

Comment: Make it 5 times faster or 5 times less frequent so it stays below 0.5%.  You have given no hint whatsoever to help you make it 5 times faster.  Making it 1bpp certainly won't help, that only saves space, not time.  The 32bppPArgb pixel format is faster by an order of magnitude than all the others.

Comment: Mh, I think that what is making the process "heavy" is all those copy (that requires also a byte processing) each time I update the image. Actually the loop has a sleep of 100 milliseconds, (quite high!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`Bitmap.LockBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) to get the underlying memory of the bitmap pinned (so the friendly garbage collector won't move it around for you).

As an example, this small program loads a png, sets a simple pixel pattern, and saves the resulting image:

```
unsafe void Main()
{
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("D:\\word.png");
    var locked = bm.LockBits(new Rectangle(0,0,bm.Width, bm.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
    try 
    {
        byte v = 0xaa;
        byte* pBuffer = (byte*)locked.Scan0;
        for(int r = 0 ; r < locked.Height ; r++) 
        {
            byte* row = pBuffer + r*locked.Stride;
            for(int c = 0 ; c < locked.Stride ; c++) 
                row[c] = v;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        bm.UnlockBits(locked);
    }
    bm.Save("D:\\generated.png");
}
```

LockBits will have an overhead depending on whether it needs to convert the internal memory representation to what you request (so it might matter where you get it from). As alwyas with performance, measure and profile to find your bottlenecks.

Comment: Well, I need a byte[] array, a C# array I mean, not a C++ byte array (because I would like to use Marshal.StructToPointer method)

Comment: ... and if you have it as a pointer, you don't need `Marshal.StructToPointer` anyways. The Marshal method, that would get you a `byte[]`, copies data, which is what you stated you do not want.

Comment: Ok LockBits is definitely the faster way I can really access to those bitmaps. I'm not happy but it's ok that's the answer