# structure intptr cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to convert the [code snippet from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629108/working-with-1bpp-images#7629133) into a VB function and I am running into a snag that I haven't seen before. 
 I'm not finding enough detail on it so I'm looking for wisdom in the ether.

```
Private Shared Function ConvertImage(filepath As String) As String
    Dim bmp As Bitmap = New Bitmap(filepath)
    Dim v As Byte = &HAA
    ' Lock the bitmap's bits. 
    Dim bmpData = bmp.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)
    Try
        Dim pBuffer As IntPtr = bmpData.Scan0
        For r As Integer = 0 To bmpData.Height Step 1
            Dim row As IntPtr = pBuffer + r * bmpData.Stride
            For c As Integer = 0 To bmpData.Stride Step 1
                row(c) = v
            Next
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData)
    End Try
    filepath = IO.Path.GetTempPath & "label.bmp"
    bmp.Save(filepath)
End Function
```

The problem is indicated to be with `row(c) = v`.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: This isn’t C#, so there’s no unsafe pointer access syntax. You’ll need to use `Marshal.Copy` back and forth from a byte array or something.

Comment: The c# code from the link is in `unsafe` scope. I am not well versed with unsafe but I may suggest you write/take the code in c#, compile it and see it through reflector or some such disassembler to see what vb.net code it generates.

Comment: You might consider compiling the C# code pretty much as it is into a library and referencing that from your VB project.

Comment: Also – is your end goal with this function to produce a bitmap of a single solid color, or is that just what it does for now?

Comment: @Ry- I need to convert RGB images to true black and white images.  Grayscale works too.  If I could replicate what MS Paint Save As Grayscale Bitmap does, it would be perfect :)

Comment: A B&W or GrayScale convertion can be achieved just applying a B&W or a GrayScale Matrix to the source Bitmap. It's as fast as LockBits(). BTW, unsafe pointers are definitely not needed to perform that task. [A B&W and Inverted B&W matrix applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521672/replacing-colour-of-an-image?answertab=active#tab-top) (C#, it but can be translated almost as it is). See the links for more informations.